# Error using if in a content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confused with this error. I am new to rails and I can't figure it out.

```
<% flash.each do |name,msg| %>
  <div class='alert alert-<%="#{name}"%>' >
    <a href="#" class='close' data-dismiss='alert' &#215; ></a>
    <%= content_tag :div , msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String); %>        
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error message is:

> syntax error, unexpected ')' if msg.is_a?(String); );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ^ /home/mody/Desktop/rails_apps/testing/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:51: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' /home/mody/Desktop/rails_apps/testing/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:53: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of syntactical problems here. Change your line to the following:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, msg, {:id => "flash_#{name}"}) if msg.is_a?(String) %>
```

1. You should wrap your `content_tag` arguments inside of parentheses to ensure that Ruby does not get confused when introducing the `if` condition
2. Ruby does not require a semi-colon at the end of a line